# What is the product of the reaction of 2-methyl-5-phenyl-2-pentene with sulfuric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

The reaction is 2-methyl-5-phenyl-2-pentene with $\ce{H2SO4 }$

[image]

I have tried multiple attempts at this question but am still getting it wrong. I have no idea why any of these answers are wrong.

I know that the chain off the aromatic ring is weak aromatic activator and an ortho-para director. I figured para would be better than ortho because of the size of the chain but obviously both answers were incorrect. I then figured that $\ce{H2SO4}$ is just a strong acid so its basically $\ce{H3O+}$ but adding $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{OH}$ across the double bond in the chain did not work either.

Comment: I think your top answer is the closest. If $\ce{H^+}$ from $\ce{H2SO4}$ adds first to the double bond, what adds to the other side? You have $\ce{HSO3^-}$ adding to the other side. Something is missing. Of course, it could be a cyclization due to Friedel-Crafts, the intramolecular verision of the top left reaction [here](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/Images2/fcalkex.gif).

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the more sure I am that you will have Friedel-Crafts-type cyclization occur.

Comment: Yes, you're right!!! I don't know how I didn't see the possibility of a Friedel- Crafts reaction, but thank you so much!! The final product was a benzene ring attached to a cyclohexane with two methyl groups coming off the bottom carbon. Once again thank you so much! I will update the question with the correct answer :)

Comment: No problem. By the way, for just an alkene, make sure you're adding $\ce{HSO4^-}$, not $\ce{HSO3^-}$. You would form an organosulfate, not an organosulfonate (or an organosulfuric acid, not an organosulfonic acid, really).

Answer (score 5):

With the help of [user SendersReagent in comments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47136/what-is-the-product-of-the-reaction-of-2-methyl-5-phenyl-2-pentene-with-sulfuric#comment77871_47136), the answer to the question was a simple intramolecular [Friedel–Crafts reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel%E2%80%93Crafts_reaction):

[image: Mechanism for formation of 1,1-dimethyl-1,2,3,4-tetrahydronaphthalene]